# Use of AWT in GWT facing some issues

Tags: java, gwt, awt

I want to use AWT in GWT. As far as I know there is one library available which is `gwt-awt.jar`.

I have downloaded it and tried to use. But I faces some issue.

> Issues are :
>
> 1. Its throws this exception : "das sind shapes"
> 2. Its not found the createTransformedArea() method from Area class.

Reason of issue - 1 :

I know from where it throws the exception. Right now this exception throws from `Area` class from below code :

```
public Area(Shape s) {
    if (s instanceof Area) {
        curves = ((Area) s).curves;
    } else {
      System.err.println("das sind shapes");
      throw new RuntimeException("das sind shapes");
//            curves = pathToCurves(s.getPathIterator(null));
    }
}
```

In the above code we can see that `curves = pathToCurves(s.getPathIterator(null));` this code commented.

My question is that why its commented?

Reason of issue - 2 :

`createTransformedArea()` not found in `Area` class because this method also commented.

How I solved this two issue?

Commented out all the necessary code from the `Area` class. After this changes this jar file working fine but still I have one problem.

Problem is, when draw shape in SuperDevMode and ClasicDevMode then found some strange issue :

In ClassicDevMode this shape draw perfectly but in SuperDevMode not draw correctly.

While I was tracking the issue the I found that some points are missing in SuperDevMode which are available in ClassicDevMode.

For example see below logs :

In ClassicDevMode :

```
Line From: (11.302, 30.539) to (11.302, 30.539)
Line from: (11.302, 30.539) to (11.302, 30.709)
Line from: (11.302, 30.709) to (11.592, 30.999)
Line from: (11.592, 30.999) to (11.762, 30.999)
```

In SuperDevMode :

```
Line from: (11.302, 30.539) to (11.302, 30.539)
Line from: (11.302, 30.539) to (11.302, 30.709)
Line from: (11.302, 30.709) to (11.346, 30.709)
```

For easy understand I am attaching the image :

[image]
[image]

Can someone help me with this issue?

Why image is not draw correctly in SuperDevMode?

Why some points are missing in SuperDevMode?